# VBA code for protecing range of cells (user intervention)

Tags: vba, excel

I want VBA code for protecting a range of cells(manually selected by user) in excel and rest of the cells will be locked. Ideally, I don't need to restrict the code for a specific range, it should allow a user to select a range of cell and lock those cells.

Please help me.

Comment: Is the range of cells you want to protect always the same? Or you want to protect cells every time you select a range? You can see the worksheet Change.

Comment: The range of cells will be varying. So I want to protect cells every time when I select a new range. And also Range can vary from first cell to last cell of excel (Row wise).

Answer (score 0):

In Change of a the worksheet, lock the cells you selected and then, protect the worksheet.

something like :

```
with thisworkbook.worksheets("the name of the worksheet")
.unprotect
Target.locked=true
.protect
end with
```

Comment: Since you'd write that in a worksheet handler (namely  `Worksheet_SelectionChange` sub) then you'd use `With Me` instead of `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("the name of the worksheet")`